# Bulk convert <a> tags to <p> tags with RegEx

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress

I have a client who runs their site on WordPress and has misinterpreted the [instructions here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/page-jumps/) and encoded all their anchors as `<a id="example-anchor"></a>` instead of `<p id="example-anchor"></p>`.

Technically the anchors work but they're incorrect and get stripped when the content gets converted for AMP (for instance).

I'm at a loss as how to specifically target these errant `<a>` tags and replace them with `<p>` tags. There appears to be roughly 70,000 instances.

I've tried `<a id=\\"([^)]+)\\"><\/a>` as well as `<a id=\\"(.*?)\\"><\/a>` among other things but they all seem to include actual `<a>` tags that need to remain.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Regex [cannot parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6243352), use a XHTML/XML parser.

Comment: What distinguishes `<a>` tags that need to remain from those that need to be converted?

Comment: @DavidFaber Sorry, I mean a actual `<a>` tags (e.g. `<a href="www.example.com">Example Link</a>`) need to remain rather than what they are currently using for anchors: `<a id="example"></a>`.

Comment: I think it might be possible to write a regular expression to do what you want to do, but I don't see a way to do it without lookaround and that's not supported in MySQL. You would probably be better off writing a script to do it (since this is WordPress, perhaps in PHP) and using an HTML/XML parser as @ggorlen suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are not using `id` and `href` in the same `a` tag, you can simply match the `a` tags you want with `<a\b([^>]+\bid=[^>]*>.*?<\/)a>` and replace them with `<p$1p>`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a new version of MySQL or MariaDB, there is no practical way to make the substitutions.

It is, however, practical to write a short PHP script (or other language) to fetch each row, fix it, then store it back.

If it is just changing `a` to `p`, then the search regexp might be `<a id=` and simply replace it with `<p id=`.  This could actually be done with with a function like `replace()` or `str_replace()`.